# Installing NumPy package in Sublimetext 3?

Tags: python, numpy, sublimetext3

I decided to use Sublimetext 3 as a quick Python editor for an upcoming assignment, but I get the error :   "No module named 'numpy'"

I assume I have to install it somewhere separately. If so, is there a more general package (scipy perhaps) that encompasses many packages such as NumPy. Thanks in advance. C

Comment: Your choice of editor is not the issue. Are you using any python package manager, like pip or Anaconda?

Comment: I have Anaconda navigator 3 installed

Comment: Hm, I don't use Anaconda myself, but it should come with numpy and a whole slew of other data-science modules. How are you running your python script? In a terminal window, what is the output of `ls -l \`which python\``? Maybe your path is inadvertently set to call your system's default python installation, rather than the Anaconda version.

Comment: If you use `conda` you most likely already have `numpy`. Try `conda install numpy`. If it is already installed, you gave sublime the wrong python installation